# HTML or JavaScript to multiply

Tags: javascript, html

Here is what I have been trying to figure out for days now. I have some code already typed up that outputs a number based on what check boxes are checked. What I want now is some code that grabs the number from that numberbox and multiplies it by a set number in a different numberbox.

Here is the JavaScript that I swiped from somewhere to try and get this to work but to no avail.

```
<script type="javascript">

function calculate() {
var myBox1 = document.getElementById('ttl').value; 
var myBox2 = document.getElementById('ttl2').value;
var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
result.innerHTML = myResult;

 }
 </script>
```

And here is the HTML that I am trying so hard to bash against it to make it work.

```
<input type="number" id="ttl" value=729><br>
<input id="result" />
```

The check boxes add more to the base of 729 and I want the lower box to multiply by 1.1

Any help out there for a code moron?

EDIT:

I don't know of much other way to ask this. I have a value that is put into a numberbox. I want a second numberbox that grabs the first box's number on the fly and multiply it by a set number which happens to be 1.1. Like I commented before, I know what I want to ask, but I don't know how to ask it exactly

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Read [JavaScript Arithmetic operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)

Comment: There isn't even a closing tag for `<input>` and it doesn't make sense to use `.innerHTML` on the `input` tag. You might use it on `textarea`, but for `<input>`, you use `.value`.

Comment: @GitaarLAB - I literally said there is no closing tag for `<input>`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: I interpreted that comment differently (as in: there should have been one). So that's what I was missing :). Sorry for my misunderstanding! I'll clean up (the comment; the other info in it is likely to be read by the OP by now).

Answer (score 3):

The element with the id `result` is an input box:

```
<input id="result" />
```

Change `result.innerHTML = myResult;` to `result.value = myResult;` and the calculated number will be displayed there. See on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jY5E/).

Comment: While this works perfectly on JSFiddle when I plug it into my code it doesn't. I see that everyone here is apparently pissed because I asked a stupid question, to which I say sorry. If this isn't the best site to ask these stupid questions, what is for the novice coder?

Comment: @Kelton The question is not stupid, it just doesn't have the information that is necessary to reproduce the problem. And without that we can't tell you what's wrong.

Comment: While I do thank you so much for your help, I feel like I took the longest route possible to get to the end result. I am usually a quick learner when it comes to code but I constantly feel like I am beating my head against a wall with Java. The whole idea is to put a list with prices and each box that checked adds to the base of 729 and then a separate box under the total gives total with tax added. I really hope this is the information you need? I know what I want to ask, but don't know how to ask it I guess. Sorry man.